# How to save JQuery layout to Database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

i am working on a 'spreadsheet'/table has collapsible rows so that you can hide/show data by clicking on a small image. I have all of this working well using JQuery and Ruby on Rails.

What I now need to do is save the layout of the table so that it persists through page loads. I understand I could do this via Ajax, writing to the database every time a user clicks a button to show/hide rows, but not sure this is the best approach. I don't think using cookies is a good approach for me either since layout should persist across browsers/sessions.

What I'm thinking of doing is this--adding hidden form fields to the page. each hidden field corresponds to one of the show/hide buttons. So, each time a button is clicked it could update (via jquery) the hidden field's value to true/false depending on whether the row is expanded or not. Then when the user saves the form I could use Rails to save the hidden field values to a hash in the database:

```
@spreadsheet.layout = {"row1_expand" => "true", "row8_expand" => "false"}
```

I'm looking for advise on best way to save layout so when the spreadsheet is viewed again it looks the same as it did when last saved. Is creating an extra field named "layout" to save a hash of values a good approach? And using hidden fields set via Jquery? I'm open to any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way you could add a CSS class to each table row when it is expanded e.g. `class="expanded"` . Then at the time the user goes to save the form, JQuery iterates through the table and flags the rows that have that class. When the player retrieves the table, you also apply the `expanded` class to the flagged rows.

Comment: hmmm, that might work, i'm reading a ton on jquery now and strategizing. your approach sounds intriguing thanks much i'll let you know what i end up doing